# How to extend a member of $Aut(G/N)$ to a member of $Aut(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group with a normal subgroup $N$. Assume in addition that $\beta$ is an automorphism of group $G/N$. My question is :

Under which conditions we can assure that there is a $\alpha \in Aut(G)$ satisfying two below conditions :

(i) $\alpha (N)=N$

(ii) $\bar \alpha = \beta$, where $\bar \alpha \in Aut(G/N)$ is the automorphism induced by $\alpha$ on $G/N$ with $\bar \alpha(Ng):= N\alpha(g)$

**Edition:** I know that this might be too general. So for a restriction consider the following question:
Apart from family of direct products, which families of groups are known to have a normal subgroup $N$ for which most of $Aut(G/N)$'s members have the above property?

Comment: simply when $N$ is characteristic subgroup in $G$.

Comment: @mesel: This doesn't suffice.

Comment: yeh, you are right, it makes converse direction is true.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too general to be answered for all quotient groups $G/N$ and $\alpha$. And there is probably no characterization of those $G$ which have this property for all $N$ and $\alpha$.

At least, we easily observe that $\beta$ may be lifted to $G$ when $\beta$ is an *inner* automorphism of $G/N$. Conversely, if $Q$ is a finite group such that every automorphism $\beta$ of $Q$ may be lifted along any surjective homomorphism $G \to Q$, then $\beta$ is an inner automorphism. The proof is a bit involved, you can find it [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finite-quotient-pullbackable_implies_inner).

Comment: "β may be lifted to G when β is an inner automorphism of G/N",  I can't see why this is true? could you explain it more?

Comment: The proof doesn't require any ideas.

Comment: Oh yes I was just confused. I got it...